# How to convert numpy array into libsvm format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, svm, libsvm

I have a numpy array for an image and am trying to dump it into the libsvm format of `LABEL I0:V0 I1:V1 I2:V2..IN:VN`. I see that scikit-learn has a `dump_svmlight_file` and would like to use that if possible since it's optimized and stable.

It takes parameters of X, y, and file output name. The values I'm thinking about would be:
X - numpy array
y - ????
file output name - self-explanatory

Would this be a correct assumption for X? I'm very confused about what I should do for y though. 
It appears it needs to be a feature set of some kind. I don't know how I would go about obtaining that however. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svmlight format is tailored to classification/regression problems. Therefore, the array `X` is a matrix with as many rows as data points in your set, and as many columns as features. `y` is the vector of instance labels.

For example, suppose you have 1000 objects (images of bicycles and bananas, for example), featurized in 400 dimensions. `X` would be 1000x400, and `y` would be a 1000-vector with a 1 entry where there should be a bicycle, and a -1 entry where there should be a banana.

Comment: That made things a lot clearer. So I have 500 images *6 classes = 3000 images. I convert them from a JPEG image to a numpy array, so I'm assuming that my X would be 3000x3 (the 3 comes from RGB dimensions). I'm still confused on what my y would be then. Is there an easy way to extend this to 6 classes, or would i have to do something like `1 if class1 else -1` for each class in the labeled classes?

Comment: Well, let's take a step back for a second... What is it that you're trying to do, eventually? Are you trying to train a multi-class classifier on your data? Is there a reason that you're exporting the data, rather than just using `sklearn.SVC`?

SVM is a binary classifier, meaning it really only handles the two-class case (though there are some generalizations to handle more classes). What people typically do is train several one-versus-all or one-vs-one classifiers, then aggregate the results.

Comment: I'm trying to train a multi-class classifier, yeah. The reason I am trying to export it is to test my data set out on the easy.py file in libsvm for a single class to test accuracy since I have no experience in this area. Ideally I would like to use `sklearn.SVC`. I am not confident enough of my skills to scale it and find C and y myself though, as well as cross-validate the results. What would you recommend to a complete beginner?

Comment: I suppose I'd recommend sticking with sklearn. It's a very nice package, and thoroughly documented. The page [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) lists several examples, such as [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#example-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py), which should help. In general, I'd try using a linear kernel first, as it's harder to overfit and only has one parameter `C`. Then you can try experimenting with RBF kernels. `sklearn` also has examples for cross-validation and parameter selection.

Comment: Great thanks for huge advice! Just to get it straight in my mind, I have to go from JPEG -> numpy array [R,G,B] -> sklearn Scale -> (I assume I get y here. I'm still confused on how I get that. See last sentence) -> sklearn Fit -> sklearn Predict -> sklearn Score. For y: Since I have an array of arrays for an image e.g.) [[255,255,255], [47,123,23], [191,63,132]], and this would be X once scaled, how would I glean y from this?

Comment: Well, `y` are class labels. So if you're trying to classify dogs, cats, birds, bananas, and bicycles, then you'd give a dog image a class of 1, a cat image a class of 2, and so on. I assume you have these labels *a priori*. If not, you're looking for clustering, not classification. So `y` will be a vector with as many entries as images, and entry `i` is a 1 if image `i` is a dog, a 2 if image `i` is a cat, and so on. `sklearn` will train a one-vs-one classifier (dog vs cat, dog vs banana, etc.) for each pair.

Comment: Okay awesome! I now concretely know what my problem is mentally. Since I have an array of arrays for 1 image. e.g.) `X =[[255,255,255], [47,123,23], [191,63,132]] y=1` is the RGB representation for Image, and an image as a whole has a class (in this case, 1) associated with it, how would I let sklean read the image? I see this problem from examples like `X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]] y = [0, 1]`, where X is an array of features, not pixels such as in my predicament. I hope I didn't make that sound more confusing than it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question -- each image should be a single row in X, not several. We're stressing the limits of the comments section. Could you message me with a bit longer explanation? We'll continue conversation there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63508/discussion-between-robert-and-jme).